# Is there a convergent improper integral for an unbounded function?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I've been wondering if an improper integral (e.g. upper bound is $\infty$) over a function that is unbounded on the integration interval can converge.

Specifically, I know the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}~dx$ does not converge, whereas
$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}~dx$ converges. I also know that $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}~dx$ does not converge, so i guess in its simplest form I'm wondering if there exists an $n$ (real?) such that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^n}~dx$$ converges.

If that form is too simple but there exists something similar I'd be interested to hear how that works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not hard to modify your example to get a positive function $f(x)$ which is continuous and unbounded on $(0, \infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ converges. One such example would be $$f(x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}};$$ we can check that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx \\
& \leq \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} + \int_1^\infty e^{-x}dx \\
&= 2 + \frac{1}{e} \\
&< \infty. \\
\end{align*}

More generally, any function of the form $f(x) = \frac{a^{-x}}{x^p}$ with $a > 1$ and $0 < p < 1$ will furnish a suitable example of a positive unbounded function on $(0, \infty)$ with convergent improper integral over that open ray.

Answer (score 3):

If $n>1$ then

$$\int_0^1x^{-n}\, dx=\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{1-n}(1-a^{1-n})$$

diverges, and if $n<1$

$$\int_1^\infty x^{-n}\, dx=\lim_{a\to \infty}\frac{1}{1-n}(a^{1-n}-1)$$

diverges. Either way,

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-n}\, dx$$

diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Tilley has indeed solved your more specific question, so I'll elaborate on the first one. Indeed, there are such integrals, in the example of [the wikipedia article about improper integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). A lot of the time those integrals can't be computed directly, but rather they used limits, substitution, and other tools such as the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).